# How much cash should I give my daughter for month long Japan trip?

Tags: japan, money

My daughter is traveling to Japan for a month. How much cash should I send with her? She has housing and 2 meals per day, but likely will be paying for a couple of meals per day. So her main costs will be food, transportation, small souvenirs, and visiting cultural/tourist sites.

Comment: I agree that this is opinion based, depends on the spending profile, etc. but maybe some help can be given. The average price meal in an average restaurant or even at known international chains. The cost of some reference products at the supermarket or the price of transport. These are objective values that may help the OP.

Comment: @nsn even if the OP understands we're not making the decision for her and are only providing a reference to make the decision herself, the provided answer would still be just a reference not an answer

Comment: Sending your daughter with a large pile of cash may not be the best option. A low-FX card might be a better bet, from which she could withdraw money + spend as needed

Comment: A little bit of cash and a couple credit cards.

Comment: Carrying a month's worth of cash seems foolhardy, even in Japan.

Comment: I will say that I think transportation will be the most wildly varying expense. If you are staying local and taking trains, it is very cheap, but if you want to travel between cities or take a taxi very far, it gets expensive. If this question weren't closed, I would be asking for clarification on that point. But since it is closed, you should know that if you use Google maps to search for directions, it will tell you what the train/bus fair will be, so you can estimate with that ;) (Also, food prices in Tokyo when I was there last month were slightly cheaper than food here in Missouri, USA.)